# My model in svm only makes predictions for one category

Tags: classification, svm, data-mining, prediction

I'm working on SVM and I'm trting to predict the drinking behaviour (drinker-no drinker), when I do the cross validation to get the best parameters and then I predict the class label, I only get predictions for one category.

```
    tune.out<-tune(svm,drinking~.,data=resp.train,kernel="linear", 
    ranges=list(cost=c(0.1,1.5,10,100),gamma=c(0.1,0.5,1,2,3,4)))
    besti<-tune.out$best.model

    pred<-predict(besti, newdata=resp.test)

    table(pred)
```

And then I get

```
    pred
    0     1 
    420   0
```

and of course this suggests that the model isn't classifing correclty. I don't know what to do, I have tried everything.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data so your problem is reproducible? Thanks :)

Comment: yeah!, sure, here you have a link to access https://expirebox.com/download/3dbaa99cf0f362e44527414a0b97071c.html